# debian install package bittwist

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I am trying to install package bittwist on debian 7.4.
Im linux newbie.

Synaptic does not display this package.
In sources.list i have line with us repository:
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main 
and i've run apt-get update

When i try to apt-get install bittwist it returns package not found.
But i see bittwist in repository:
http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/bittwist/

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bittwist` package is not in the `wheezy` release. You can see [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=bittwist&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) that it is only in `oldstable`, `wheezy-backports`, `jessie` and `sid`.

If you want to install `bittwist`, add the wheezy-backports repository to your `sources.list`, run `apt-get update`, and then `apt-get install bittwist` will install it.

The line you should add to your `sources.list` is:

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main
```